# How to bypass touch events from transparent overlapping view to underlying view

Tags: react-native

I have two views. View 1 is the bottom view and View 2 overlaps view 1.
View 2 is used for some representational purpose and view 1 performs user touch handling. Since View 2 is covering View1, we are not receiving touch events is View1.

How can we bypass touch events from view 2 to view 1 ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a `pointerEvents:'none'` property to the top View and you'll be able to click through it to the bottom View.